# how does it set the height of the div properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to responsive css layout.
I have the following code.

```css
.parent{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #eee;
}

.child{
  margin-top:30px;
  font-size:18pt;
  border:4px solid #ff6600;
  padding:20px;
  color:#f00;
}

.footer{
   background-color:#333;
   color:#fff;
}

img{
  width:100%;
  z-index:-10;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://www.vacations-abroad.com/assets/img/about.jpg">
  <div class="child">
    The responsive design:<br>
    This is the content.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
   Footer
</div>
```

The content has to placed above the image.
I want to place the "footer" after both of image and content text  whenever the window width is small and the image height is small less than the content textbox height.
But "footer" overlaid to the image.
How could I fix this issue?
Thanks.
When changing the window width, the following result will get.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Set the `.parent` height to the height of img.

Comment: This is because you're using `position: relative;` on the `parent`. Why are you setting the image using absolute positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  tag has the absolute position, so the height of this tag doesn't depend on the height of .parent div.
To resolve the issue , you have to set the min-height of the parent tag same as the content or image height.

Try this code.

```css
    .parent{
      position:relative;
      border:1px solid #eee;
      min-height:180px;
    }

    .child{
      margin-top:30px;
      font-size:18pt;
      border:4px solid #ff6600;
      padding:20px;
      color:#f00;
      position:absolute;
    }

    .footer{
       background-color:#333;
       color:#fff;
    }

    img{
      width:100%;
      z-index:-10;
      position:relative;
      top:0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    The responsive design:<br>
    This is the content.
  </div><img src="https://www.vacations-abroad.com/assets/img/about.jpg">

</div>
<div class="footer">
   Footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this way. i have remove the absolute position of the image, and add `absolute` to `.child` class

```css
.parent{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #eee;
}

.child{
  margin-top:30px;
  font-size:18pt;
  border:4px solid #ff6600;
  padding:20px;
  color:#f00;
 position: absolute; /* newly added */
 top: 60px; /* newly added */
 left: 0; /* newly added */
 width: 100%; /* newly added */
}

.footer{
   background-color:#333;
   color:#fff;
}

img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://www.vacations-abroad.com/assets/img/about.jpg">
  <div class="child">
    The responsive design:<br>
    This is the content.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
   Footer
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some information what you've done and why.

Comment: I want to place the "footer" after both of "image" and content text", but when the image height is less than "content text" height, the footer will overlay the "content text".

Comment: I've added images when the windows changing. I want to place the "footer" after image and content always. But in the first image, the footer overlaid the image.

Answer (score 1):

I have made two changes to your code.

(1) I changed the images `position` to `relative` [Read up on positioning here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

(2) I swapped the location of your `img` tag in your html to after the `.child` tag. This way it is placed above the image.

```css
.parent{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #eee;
}

.child{
  margin-top:30px;
  font-size:18pt;
  border:4px solid #ff6600;
  padding:20px;
  color:#f00;
}

.footer{
   background-color:#333;
   color:#fff;
}

img{
  width:100%;
  z-index:-10;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    The responsive design:<br>
    This is the content.
  </div><img src="https://www.vacations-abroad.com/assets/img/about.jpg">

</div>
<div class="footer">
   Footer
</div>
```

If you wanted to have a background image, it may be 'better' to use a `background-image` property (see below);

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.child {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border: 4px solid #ff6600;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #f00;
  background: url("https://www.vacations-abroad.com/assets/img/about.jpg"); /*this can be cached*/
  min-height: 500px;  /* sets a minimum height*/
}

.footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    The responsive design:<br> This is the content.
  </div>
  <!--No need for img tag!-->
</div>
<div class="footer">
  Footer
</div>
```

Comment: Why does the text content have the white color background?

Comment: This is because it is "above" the image. If you wanted this to be **on top of* the image (i.e. layered), have a look at my second example

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a height to the `.parent` because your `<img>` is absolute position.

```
.parent{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  height: 350px; /* example of height */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you define position absolute on your image, this will result in the image being excluded from the page flow, thus your footer ignores the Image.

Try setting the height of your parent element equal to the height of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Change the position of the content and remove the absolut position:

[Your fixed code](https://jsfiddle.net/bty42pp3/)

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.child {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border: 4px solid #ff6600;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #f00;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">
    The responsive design:<br> This is the content.
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.vacations-abroad.com/assets/img/about.jpg">
</div>
<div class="footer">
  Footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

whats happening is that the height of the element is being set to all relative positioned content within it, and it is ignoring the absolutely positioned image.

What you will need to do is add the following to the css:

```
.parent{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w9h9ee04/

Feel free to look at my jsfiddle to see how this works. From here you'll just need to set the height of parent to whatever the height of the image is.

Edit:

here is an alternative solution. Instead of absolutely positioning the image, you can absolutely position the floating text box. Please see this new jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/p11bu007/

Here is the updated css:

```
.parent{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #eee;
}

.child{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:18pt;
  border:4px solid #ff6600;
  padding:20px;
  color:#f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
}

.footer{
   background-color:#333;
   color:#fff;
}

img{
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the image to be position absolute so it will overlap everything. Why don't you use background to achieve the effect you need?

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: url('https://www.vacations-abroad.com/assets/img/about.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border: 4px solid #ff6600;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #f00;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    The responsive design:<br> This is the content.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  Footer
</div>
```

Comment: True but it makes the background image responsive. If you want to make sure it shows the whole image you could do background-size: contain;